# How to connect multiple variables into one vector

Tags: r

I have variables from `c1` to `c24`, totally 24 variables. I want to do something like:

```
  b <- c(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,
        c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,
        c18,c19,c20,c21,c22,c23,c24)
```

How could I do this ? It is not working to use something like `b <- c(c 1:c24)`, R only connects two values (`c1` and `c24`) in this case, but I want to put all 24 values into this vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `lapply` and `get`:

```
c1 <- c2 <- c3 <- c4 <- 1
unlist(                   ## convert from list to vector
    lapply(               
        paste0("c",1:4),  ## names of variables
        get)              ## retrieve variable by name
)
## [1] 1 1 1 1
```

In general, it would be a good idea to look further back in your workflow and see if it's possible to generate those variables within a list in the first place ...

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very useful. The reason why I get a number of these variables is that I use the for loop to generate many variables. Thanks very much, it works !

Comment: Or without `lapply` using something like `unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "c\\d+")))`

Comment: @David, thanks. your code is also worked. However, the sequence is something like "c1, c10, c11...", is there any possible that the order would be "c1, c2, c3, c4, .."

Comment: How are you generating the variables in the for loops?  With `assign`? If you have a loop `for (i in 1:24) ...` you can/should just create an empty vector or list first, then fill the values into the vector/list as you go along.

Comment: @Tom You can just do `unlist(mget(paste0("c",1:4)))` if you don't want to use regex

Comment: @Ben, Yes I used the assign. I have no idea about how to create an empty vector. I think you are right. Once I create a vector, I can use the formula to calculate the result from the vector.